# How to pass object to client using Websockets? (use object class from js file in html script)

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, websocket

In my index.js I have a class

```
class Digit() {
//construct

add() {
//do whatever
}
}
```

and

```
let C = new Digit();
```

I pass this to the client using

```
WS.send(JSON.stringify(C))
```

which is recieved/interpreted in index.html. This all works perfectly and the issue is not with this proccess.

However when I try to use C.add(), I get the TypeError: function add does not exist. In my eyes either the error is that there is no 'context' for the class and thus the methods cannot be accessed, there is some namespace error, or JSON.stringify cannot properly send objects of custom classes. So how do I fix this error?

Comment: JSON passes data -- strings and integers.  It doesn't pass classes, nor does it pass functions.  You will need the class definition at both ends.